# permisions for procedure / outfile / prepared statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, mariadb

I have a stored procedure in which I have a prepared statement for select ... into outfile.
When I try to call that procedure as root, it works well, but I keep getting access denied when I try to call it as another user.

```
Show grants:
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'mls'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mls`.* TO 'mls'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in MySQL 5.5:

Login as root

```
USE mls;
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'mls'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ...;
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON `mls`.* TO 'mls'@'localhost';
CREATE TABLE t1 ( a INT );
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc() begin select * from t1 into outfile 'into_outfile'; END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Login as mls

```
USE mls;
CALL simpleproc();
```

For MariaDB you need the SUPER privilege: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-manipulation/select-into-dumpfile/

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not even thought that the permisions can differ on MariaDB.